# Tengo una situación con AJAX al llamar un método en ASP

Tags: html, c#, ajax, asp, webforms

espero me puedan ayudar.

Tengo una tabla en html donde al final tengo un botón que llama a un JS (hasta acá todo bien) y este a su vez llama al método en el ASP me da da este error (https://localhost:44383/Liq_Fact.aspx/Procesar_Click 500).

HTML (parte de la tabla)

```
 <input type="button" name="btnAsociar" onclick="Procesar( <% = item.IDLiquidacion  %> )"  value="Asociar">
```

JS

```
<script type: "text/javascript">
            function Procesar(idliquidacion) {
               /* alert(idliquidacion)*/
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    Swal.fire({
                        title: 'Asociar',
                        text: "Estas seguro que deseas Asociar la liquidación " + idliquidacion + "?",
                        icon: 'question',
                        showCancelButton: true,
                        confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                        cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                        confirmButtonText: 'Sí, envíar!',
                        cancelButtonText: 'Cancelar'
                    }).then((result) => {
                        if (result.isConfirmed) {
                            $.ajax({
                                type: "Post", //POST
                                url: "Liq_Fact.aspx/Procesar_Click",
                                data: {idliquidacion: idliquidacion},
                                contentType: "application/json",
                                dataType: "text",
                                success: function (msg) {
                                    console.log(msg.d);
                                },
                                failure: function (response) {
                                    alert(response.d);
                                },
                                error: function (response) {
                                    alert(response.d);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    })
                });
            }
    </script>
```

C# asp.net

```
 [WebMethod]
 public static string  Procesar_Click(int id)
    {
        string texto = "Hola"; 
        return texto;
    }
```